# Is ghusl once in a week Fard? I am not asking Friday ghusl that's different

Tags: ghusl, jumuah

I have read a hadith in Sahih bukhari and Muslim where it is mentioned that taking bath once in a week is right of Allah on his slaves. This hadith proves it is compulsory to take bath in once a week but scholar have used this hadith in reference to Friday Ghusl although nothing is mentioned in this hadith as such. I do understand that Friday Ghusl ahadith exist but this hadith which i gave quoted is different one. Friday Ghusl is not fard as it is proven by ahadith. I do understand that friday ghusl is considered fard hy some scholars like Shaykh Albani, Ibn Hazm, Shaykh Uthaymeen, Shaykh Muqbil etc. But when we analyse we come to come it is not fard as mentioned in hadith of Muslim and Abu Dawud. I feel when we collect all hadith we come to know that bath once in a week is fard because ALLAH's right must come in frad category and the day which is preferred for bath is friday.

So friday bath is recommended but bath once in a week is fard

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question: Is ghusl once in a week fard? If no then why? Because we have a clear cut hadith that I have already quoted above that Ghusl once in a week is compulsory

Comment: You haven't quoted any hadith and there's no consensus on ghusl being fard neither on Friday nor once a week. Further the question content should make clear what you inquire while in this case this looks like a statement or an expression of your own view which you failed to support by evidences. As for the hadith used as an evidence for Friday ghusl the majority say that the statement used doesn't support regarding it fard and this was covered on the site already.